# How to retain the first instance of a match with sed

Tags: regex, sed, sh

I have a set of tokens in data and wish to strip off the trailing `".[0-9]"`, however i cannot figure out how to quote the regexp properly. The First match should be all up to the `.` and the second the `.` and a number. I am intending that the first match be retained.

```
data="thing thing__aaa.0 thing__bbb.3 thing__ccc.5 other_aaa other_bbb other_ccc.5"
data=`echo $data | sed s/\([a-zA-Z0-9_]+\)\(\.[0-9]\)/\1/g`
echo $data
```

Actual output:

```
thing thing__aaa.0 thing__bbb.3 thing__ccc.5 other_aaa other_bbb other_ccc.5
```

Desired output:

```
thing thing__aaa thing__bbb thing__ccc other_aaa other_bbb other_ccc
```

The idea is that the unquoted `([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)` is the first matching group, and the `(\.[0-9])` matches the `.number`. the `\1` should replace both groups with the first group.

Comment: Are you escaping the parentheses?

Comment: @all, Ive Clarified the question, hope that helps, And i did not downvote anyone....!

Comment: You are nearly there except that the `+` needs to be `\+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just

```
echo $data | sed 's/\.[0-9]//g'
```

or if number may contain more digits, then

```
echo $data | sed 's/\.[0-9]\+//g'
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just want to delete all strings of the form `\.[0-9]`.  So why not just do:

```
sed 's/\.[0-9]+\b//g'
```

(This relies on gnu sed's `\b` and `+` extensions.  For other sed you can do:

```
sed 's/\.[0-9][0-9]*\( \|$\)/\1/g'
```

Answer (score -1):

I normally don't encourage the use of shell specific extensions, but if you are using bash you might be happy using an array:

```
bash$ data=(thing thing__aaa.0 thing__bbb.3)
bash$ echo "${data[@]%.[0-9]*}"
```

Note that this will also delete extensions that are not all digits (ie `foo.34bb`), but perhaps is adequate for your needs.)